# File content variable value

Tags: php, get, include

first.php:

```
<?php
$name ="somthing";
?>
```

second.php

```
$data = file_get_contents(first.php);
```

Now I want get **$name** variable value from **$data** variable. How to do it?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: that's not how `file_get_contents()` works. use `include()` instead

Comment: Yes, you can use include or require function for it and you would be able to fetch the variable from file.

Comment: file_get_contents() is to get raw contents from a file. Not dynamic or logical values.

Answer (score 2):

change second.php to:

```
include 'first.php';
echo $name;
```

Output will be "somthing"

Answer (score 1):

You should use **include**, **include_once**, **require** or **require_once** functions, **file_get_contents** get a file content as a string without parsing it.

Syntax:

```
include 'first.php';
```

or

```
require 'first.php';
```

> In PHP, you can insert the content of one PHP file into another PHP file before the server executes it.
>
> The include and require statements are used to insert useful codes written in other files, in the flow of execution.
>
> Include and require are identical, except upon failure:
>
> require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script
>   include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue

[More details](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

How to make it working?

**first.php**

`<?php $name ="somthing"; ?>`

**second.php**

`<?php 
  include 'first.php';
  echo $name;
 ?>`

it will print the content of variable **$name**